# How to add new MongoClient in cakephp 3x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.2

How to add

```
new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost');
```

in cakephp 3x __construct . I am trying to setup mongodb in cakephp-3.2, and also is there any plugin for cakephp3.2 to have mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31274207/4244742 . To bring 3rd party class we need to add class file in vendor folder and then we need to use 
`require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . "my_library_folder" . DS . "my_library_base_class.php")` in bootstrap.php. Now you can use it AppController under `parent::initialize();`