# App::import not working for Vendor php cake 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I added a new vendor to my file but when I wrote the App:import it is gives the error `Error: Class 'App\Controller\App' not found`.

Code:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'php-excel-reader/excel_reader2');
```

the file is in `vendor\php-excel-reader\excel_reader2`
It used to work for my php 2.x codes. So I wonder if things changed for cake 3.x. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562930/how-to-import-vendor-files-in-cakephp-3x

Comment: already tried that. still getting "Error: Class 'App\Controller\excel_reader2' "
when I add the  $my_obj = new excel_reader2();

Comment: It doesn't seem to be loaded through composer, use this require_once(ROOT . 'vendor' . DS  . 'php-excel-reader' . DS . 'excel_reader2' . DS . 'your_class_file.php');

Comment: @JazzCat yup that the one I tried, after I added that there will be no error, then when I add "$my_obj = new excel_reader2(); " its gives back that error

Comment: is the class name excel_reader2, is the filename excel_reader2.php ? Seems weird to name a class excel_reader2, try new excel_reader();

Comment: the file is in : vendor\php-excel-reader\excel_reader2.php, its a php functionality that works on native php. But when I apply it on cake it does not work due to directory issue

Comment: You only answered half of jazz cats questions, the question was whether there really is such a class, and looking at  **https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-excel-reader/**, which I can only guess is what you're trying to use (?), there is no such class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import vendor files in CakePHP 3x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562930/how-to-import-vendor-files-in-cakephp-3x)

Answer (score 0):

### [Finding Paths to Namespaces](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/app.html)

```
static Cake\Core\App::path(string $package, string $plugin = null)
```

> Used to get locations for paths based on conventions:
>
> // Get the path to Controller/ in your application
>
> ```
> App::path('Controller');
> ```